# How to object name paramerters in java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How to object name paramerters in java hibernate?

```
    String supplierHql = "from Supplier where name='Kamil'";
    Query supplierQuery = session.createQuery(supplierHql);
    Supplier supplierr = (Supplier) supplierQuery.list().get(0); // ilk değerini aldık


    String hql = "from Product as product  where product.supplier=:supplierr";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List resulList = query.list();
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to set object paraperter to sql query?  I want to tell ,"String hql = "from Product as product  where product.supplier=:Object", I can not do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String hql = "from Product as product  where product.supplier=:supplierr";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter("supplierr", "7277")
.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql = "from Product as product where product.supplier='"+ supplier.getSupplier() + "'";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List resulList = query.list();
```

Comment: This method of query construction is not recomended I will lead to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability

Comment: Ok another why for Preventing sql injection is  `String hql = "from Product as product where product.supplier=?";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List resulList = querysetString(0, supplier.getSupplier()).list();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use namedQuery. 
Exp :Define namedQueries in your entity.

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findProductBySupplier",
            query="from Product p where p.supplier = :supplier")})
```

/*
   Hibernate 5 previous multiple define namedQuery in namedQueries tag, after 5 define many namedQuery not used NamedQueries.
*/

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Product.findProductBySupplier").setString("supplier", "kamil");
query.list(); //or uniqueResult();
```

you should look this tutorial.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa-named-query-example/

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named